# Binding on recursive forEach only works one-way, changes are not stored

Tags: jsf, recursion, el

I'm rendering a tree of nodes recursively using the following two JSF composite components I created:

## tree.xhtml:

```
...

<cc:implementation>

  <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.rootNode.children}" var="node">
                <ui:include src="treeNode.xhtml">
                   <ui:param name="level" value="1" />
                </ui:include>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </h:panelGroup>

</cc:implementation>
```

## treeNode.xhtml:

```
...

<cc:implementation>

    <li>
        #{node.label}
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{node.checked}" />
        <c:if test="#{not empty node.children}">
            <ul class="node-level-#{level}">
                <c:forEach items="#{node.children}" var="node">
                    <ui:include src="treeNode.xhtml">
                       <ui:param name="level" value="#{level + 1}" />
                    </ui:include>
                </c:forEach>
            </ul>
        </c:if>
    </li>

</cc:implementation>
```

Every Node has the properties `label, checked,` and `children` (the latter being a list of Nodes).

I'm getting it all nicely rendered, but when I try to change values, by checking the checkboxes and submitting the form, it doesn't get stored. Next time I refresh the page I still get the initial state (all checkboxes unchecked).

What am I doing wrong?